# How can I find second argument of pow function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pow

I have `pow(m, d, n)` result. In my case it is equal to :

```
12225498137150622354554250184405886100508699329229959905596279621592733966424932153866414082797232289879676644517642340440240161204602427312536305468214644532111912949963975812138577993625598594245584019028928828150931653900411395887618683118038092556530082085484098552218318785602805935815273018117468338995732086300651871687460552498970338703456792250145170370440374473385694706721205868268156557118786149300770779251388948623826315673489012414613428155141567393632320643884413526775577956631856461996540427376948607024551355988486776124589799992688088774390496099778643837166453399795934207646722218843651340776522.
```

Also I have the first argument (`m`), that equal to `1633771873`.
And I have the third argument (`n`), that in my case equal to :

```
26507591511689883990023896389022361811173033984051016489514421457013639621509962613332324662222154683066173937658495362448733162728817642341239457485221865493926211958117034923747221236176204216845182311004742474549095130306550623190917480615151093941494688906907516349433681015204941620716162038586590895058816430264415335805881575305773073358135217732591500750773744464142282514963376379623449776844046465746330691788777566563856886778143019387464133144867446731438967247646981498812182658347753229511846953659235528803754112114516623201792727787856347729085966824435377279429992530935232902223909659507613583396967.
```

But I do not know the second argument. How can I find it?
I will be very grateful for the help.

Now I'm trying to use brute force, but it seems to last incredibly long.

I also have a case where the second and third arguments are known, and I need to find the first one. I have difficulties with that too.

Comment: the discrete logarithm... a key element of some cryptographic algorithms and hence why it might take a long (long) time..

Comment: Looks like you trying to reverse an asymmetric encryprion key. That's a task so hard to do that it is actually base of widely used security systems.

Comment: there is no non brute force solution, this is why its used in encryption

Comment: If I would know a way a to do that I would keep it secret and be very rich or alternatively break the internet as we know it.

Comment: :hmm: It sounds true. Maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction. But I still do not leave hopes for brute force :D

Comment: try [this](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/asymmetric-crypto/discrete-logarithm-problem-YqxXQ) coursera thing if you want to understand a little better as to why you cant do what you want to do

Comment: Okay, I get it.
And if I want to know the first argument, knowing the second and third, then my chances are the same?